# Having difficulty understanding Java regex interpretation

Tags: java, regex

Can someone help me with the following Java regex expression? I've done some research but I'm having a hard time putting everything together.

The regex:

```
"^-?\\d+$"
```

My understandning of what each symbol does:

1. `"` = matches the beginning of the line
2. `-` = indicates a range
3. `?` = does not occur or occurs once
4. `\\d` = matches the digits
5. `+` = matches one or more of the previous thing.
6. `$` = matches end of the line

Is the regex saying it only want matches that start or end with digits? But where do `-` and `?` come in?

Comment: `^` is start of string, not `"`. And `-` is not a range, it's a literal `-` character.

Comment: this regex match positive or negative numbers

Comment: The `"`s wrap this in a java string. It's a regular expression for a possible negative integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-` only indicates a range if it's within a character class (i.e. square brackets `[]`). Otherwise, it's a normal character like any other. With that in mind, this regex matches the following examples:

- `"-2"`
- `"3"`
- `"-700"`
- `"436"`

That is, a positive or negative integer: at least one digit, optionally preceded by a minus sign.

Answer (score 3):

Some regex is composed, as you have now, the correct way to read your regex is :

- `^` start of word
- `-?` optional minus character
- `\\d+` one or more digits
- `$` end of word

This regex match any positive or negative numbers, like `0`, `-15`, `558`, `-19663`, ...

Fore details check this good post [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 3):

`"^-?\\d+$"` is not a regex, it's a Java string literal.

Once the compiler has parsed the string literal, the string value is `^-?\d+$`, which is a regex matching like this:

```
^    Matches beginning of input
-    Matches a minus sign
?      Makes previous match (minus sign) optional
\d   Matches a digit (0-9)
+      Makes previous match (digit) match repeatedly (1 or more times)
$    Matches end of input
```

All-in-all, the regex matches a positive or negative integer number of unlimited length.

*Note:* A `-` only denotes a range when inside a `[]` character class, e.g. `[4-7]` is the range of characters between `'4'` and `'7'`, while `[3-]` and `[-3]` are not ranges since the start/end value is missing, so they both just match a `3` or `-` character.